# How to LTRIM/RTRIM specific chars?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this `nvarchar` string for **example**:

```
declare @s as nvarchar(max)
set @s = '  ##a# bc##   ###'
```

So I need the spaces to be trimed but also the `#` chars.
How can I return just `'a# bc'`?

(number of leading and trailing `#` may vary)

Comment: Do you expect # to appear anywhere else? or just leading/trailing? Always 3 ###?

Comment: @gbn, yes. I will update my question. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following generic functions to cut arbitrary leading and trailing chars, by simply calling

```
dbo.LTrimX(dbo.RTrimX(' ##a# bc### ', ' #'), ' #')
```

Here the UDFs (adapted from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/10/sql-server-2008-enhenced-trim-function-remove-trailing-spaces-leading-spaces-white-space-tabs-carriage-returns-line-feeds/)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX), @trimchars VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
     AS
     BEGIN  
     IF @str LIKE '[' + @trimchars + ']%'
     SET @str =STUFF ( @str , 1 , PATINDEX('%[^' + @trimchars + ']%', @str)-1 , '')
     RETURN @str
END

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RTrimX(@str VARCHAR(MAX), @trimchars VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
     AS
     BEGIN
     IF @str LIKE '%[' + @trimchars + ']' 
     SET @str = REVERSE(dbo.LTrimX(REVERSE(@str), @trimchars))
     RETURN @str
END
GO
```

Comment: Can I safely change `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` in your functions?

Comment: As all involved functions support `NVARCHAR` I'd say yes, but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the abc part is only ever made up of numbers and letters:

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(50)
SET @s = ' ##a# bc### '

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(@s,PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9]%',@s),LEN(@s) - PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9]%',REVERSE(@s)) -1) as string2
```